# Cannot Get Required Data Object From Vue Component

Tags: json, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I've been working on a project in vue. I have a component `Subreddit.vue`. The component contains a form in the template that gets the data from the form and passes that data into an object called `post`. Then a method `onCreatePost()` that gets called on submitting the form passes that to a store file subreddit.js which has an action called `createPost(post)` that accepts the post object and gets it's document reference and inserts the data into the database.

The code for `Subreddit.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <h1>{{ $route.params.name }}</h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="onCreatePost()">
      <b-field label="Title">
        <b-input v-model="post.title"></b-input>
      </b-field>
      <b-field label="Description">
        <b-input type="textarea" v-model="post.description"></b-input>
      </b-field>
      <b-field label="URL" >
        <b-input v-model="post.URL" type="url"></b-input>
      </b-field>
      <button class="button is-success">Add Post</button>
    </form>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      post: {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        URL: '',
      },
    };
  },
  computed: mapState('subreddit', ['posts']),
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('subreddit', ['createPost']),
    async onCreatePost() {
      if (this.post.title && (this.post.description || this.post.URL)) {
        await this.createPost(this.post);
        console.log(this.post); // eslint-disable-line no-console
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The code for the store `subreddit.js`:

```js
import { firestoreAction } from 'vuexfire'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
import db from '@/db';

const posts = db.collection('posts');

const state = {
  posts: [],
};

const actions = {
  async createPost(post) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    console.log(post) // eslint-disable-line no-console
    const result = posts.doc();
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    post.id = result.id;
    const postDoc = posts.doc(post.id);
    await postDoc.set(post);
  },
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  actions,
};
```

Theoretically when i `console.log(post)` (the parameter of the `createPost()` in the store subreddit.js whose value is received from the given vue component), it should contain an object with the data that i have received from the given component. However it returns this:

```
{getters: {…}, state: {…}, rootGetters: {…}, dispatch: ƒ, commit: ƒ, …}
commit: ƒ (_type, _payload, _options)
dispatch: ƒ (_type, _payload, _options)
getters: {}
id: "N5S3uQvzTrGHnkZTuqMh"
rootGetters: {}
rootState:
auth: (...)
subreddit: (...)
subreddits: (...)
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get auth: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set auth: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get subreddit: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set subreddit: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get subreddits: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set subreddits: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__: Object
state: {__ob__: Observer}
__proto__: Object
```

I cannot make sense of this object that is returned nor does it have any data that i have passed in the component. How do i get that data ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Eggon in the comments for his answer, it was indeed a problem with firestore. Apparently, if the attributes in the JSON object you are sending to the firestore database aren't complete, then the database won't allow you to enter data into itself. That is just a hypotheses. I could be wrong, but i tried everything and decided it was useless and went back to coding the project, and the error completely disappeared and i was able to make an entry into the database. The project is on my [GitHub](https://github.com/DivineDemon/reddit-clone) if you need to check it out.

Answer (score -1):

When you refer from template to handler methods you should not use (), just the name of the method. Try changing

`@submit.prevent="onCreatePost()"`
to
`@submit.prevent="onCreatePost"`

Comment: So leave them removed. :) Try putting the `console.log` before await and logging each property of `this.post` separately to force evaluation of the object and see what is being passed to the action. Console log is an async function itself, so  it doesn't log objects accurately at the moment it is called.

Comment: as you suggested, i've left the parentheses removed and put `console.log` before the await in the `onCreatePost()`. i'm getting the correct values there, but the issue still persists and i'm getting a new error `Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a function` .

Comment: Well it must be some a problem with firestore then, I don't know firestore api unfortunatelly, so I can't help you anymore. Check their docs on the methods you are using in the action.